# Searching the Owned Members of a Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: grails, has-many

With Book and Author domain classes as follows:

```
class Book { 
    static belongsTo = Author
    static hasMany = [authors:Author]
    String title
}

class Author {
   static hasMany = [books:Book]
   String name
}
```

How would I find the book by an author that has the title "Grails"?

I tried this but it didn't work (No signature of method: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.findByTitle() is applicable for arguemnt types: (java.lang.String) value: [Grails].

```
Author author = Author.get(1)
def book = author.books.findByTitle("Grails")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search by example as follows.

```
Author author = Author.get(1) def b = Book.find( new Book(title:'grails', author:author) )
```

see [this link](http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+Querying) for info on how to do querys.

Comment: This is what I needed with a minor correction. I have an author instance, so the code becomes:

    Author author = Author.get(1)
    def b = Book.find( new Book(title:'grails', author:author) )

Thanks!